# Single SQL query required

Tags: sql

I have two tables as follows

```
companyid name      
1         pwc       
2         dell      
3         microsoft 
4         google    
5         yahoo     
6         twitter   

companyid  state        month   powerconsumption

1          newyork       jan    240
2          california    jan    130    
3          arizona       jan    210
4          texas         jan    130
5          texas         jan    650
6          california    jan    310
2          arizona       jan    340
```

I want to have a query to list the companies in each state in terms of power consumption(highest to lowest) in the month of jan.So the result in case of above data will be

```
arizona    dell      340
arizona    microsoft 210        
california twitter   310
california dell      130
newyork    pwc       240
texas      yahoo     650
texas      google    130
```

Comment: This is very basic SQL. Read about table joins and sorting and you can figure it out by yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t2.state, t1.name,t2.powerconsumption
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.companyId = t2.companyId
WHERE t2.month = 'jan'
ORDER BY t2.state ASC, t2.powerconsumption DESC;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0709a/1)</kbd>

This JOINS both tables, then sorts first by state ASCending and secondly by powerconsumption DESCendingly. This means that it will be sorted descendingly for each state.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply a filter to the second table to only return January records.

You then need to link rows from the company table (t1) to the power consumption table (t2). Linking is accomplished through they keyword `JOIN`. Joins come in different flavors but the type you will be interested in is an `INNER JOIN`. "I only want rows that exist in both tables." As part of your join, you will need to describe how rows should be matched. This is the `ON` specifier (and might also include `AND` and `OR` in the event there are multiple parts to the key).

Results from queries have no order unless you explicitly specify them. I don't care what you might observe in that they are returned in the same order every time you run the query. If there is no `ORDER BY` clause, you are not *guaranteed* to have results in any order. I am sorting your results based on the stated, followed by company name and then by power consumption descending.

```
SELECT 
    PC.state
,   C.name
,   PC.powerconsumption
FROM 
    company C
    INNER JOIN 
        power_consumption PC 
        ON PC.companyId = C.companyId
WHERE 
    PC.month = 'jan'
ORDER BY 
    PC.state ASC
,   C.name ASC
,   PC.powerconsumption DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this is realy simple. Did you try to work the problem around?

```
Select data.state, company.name, data.powerconsumption
From company
inner join data on data.companyid  =company.companyid
```